# Haskell - Exclude lists based on a test in a nested list comprehension

Tags: haskell, filter, list-comprehension

I want to create a series of possible equations based on a general specification:

```
test = ["12", "34=", "56=", "78"]
```

Each string (e.g. "12") represents a possible character at that location, in this case '1' or '2'.)
So possible equations from test would be "13=7" or "1=68".
I know the examples I give are not balanced but that's because I'm deliberately giving a simplified short string.
(I also know that I could use 'sequence' to search all possibilities but I want to be more intelligent so I need a different approach explained below.)

What I want is to try fixing each of the equals in turn and then removing all other equals in the equation.  So I want:

```
[["12","=","56","78"],["12","34","=","78”]]
```

I've written this nested list comprehension:
(it needs: {-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-} )

```
fixEquals :: [String] -> [[String]]
fixEquals re
  = [
      [
        if index == outerIndex then equals else remain 
        | equals <- map (filter (== '=')) re
        | remain <- map (filter (/= '=')) re
        | index <- [1..]
      ]

      | outerIndex <- [1..length re]
    ]
```

This produces:

```
[["","34","56","78"],["12","=","56","78"],["12","34","=","78"],["12","34","56","”]]
```

but I want to filter out any with empty lists within them.  i.e. in this case, the first and last.

I can do:

```
countOfEmpty :: (Eq a) => [[a]] -> Int 
countOfEmpty = length . filter (== [])

fixEqualsFiltered :: [String] -> [[String]]
fixEqualsFiltered re = filter (\x -> countOfEmpty x == 0) (fixEquals re)
```

so that "fixEqualsFiltered test" gives:

```
[["12","=","56","78"],["12","34","=","78”]]
```

which is what I want but it doesn’t seem elegant.
I can’t help thinking there’s another way to filter these out.
After all, it’s whenever "equals" is used in the if statement and is empty that we want to drop the equals so it seems a waste to build the list (e.g. ["","34","56","78”] and then ditch it.)

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Better put the innner list comprehension for `fixEquals` in a separated function.

Comment: Are these sequences of possible characters the original form of the constraint, or are they derived from some more... sensible... constraints? If the latter, what are the original constraints?

Comment: I'm creating arithmetic puzzles where the answers are equations. Sometimes I say directly what some of the symbols are.  This means that I might know that an equation is "49??=??3" and I need to find all equations which fit that template.  In this case "49/7=4+3" or "49*7=343" would be possible solutions.  Sometimes I give that a symbol is a digit "0123456789" or an operator "+-*/" without specifying it exactly - just give a set of possibilities.  Does that explain why I'm choosing the constraints as I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is any cleaner than your code, but it might be a bit more clear and maybe more efficient using a recursion:

```
fixEquals = init . f
f :: [String] -> [[String]]
f [] = [[]]
f (x:xs) | '=' `elem` x = ("=":removeEq xs) : map (removeEq [x] ++) (f xs)
         | otherwise    = map (x:) (f xs)

removeEq :: [String] -> [String]
removeEq = map (filter (/= '='))
```

The way it works is that, if there's an `'='` in the current string, then it splits the return into two, if not just calls recursively. The `init` is needed as in the last element returned there's no equal in any string.

Finally, I believe you can probably find a better data structure to do what you need to achieve instead of using list of strings

Comment: Thanks @Lorenzo - certainly solves my problem more clearly. You tantalizingly suggest I could probably find a better data structure - any thoughts on the type of thing I might explore?

Comment: @Adahus what is the real problem you want to solve/are working on?

Comment: @Elmex80s My overall program involves finding arithmetic equations which fit certain masks.  I tried generating all sequences of characters and then parsing to see if they are balanced equations but it was too inefficient as I was trying loads of totally invalid strings (e.g. "999+=").  I am now implementing a new approach which requires the routine discussed above.  I am confident of the improved efficiency as I have previously implemented much of it in Swift but I want to translate into Haskell and as I'm learning Haskell it seems best to build from the bottom up.  Thanks for asking.

Comment: Yes, usually the approach in Haskell is completely different from what you'd use in imperative programming. I can't really understand what you want to do but I'd say having the `=` in a string doesn't seem right. Maybe have a look at the Either monad or make your own data type

Comment: To Swift's credit it does move into the functional programming realm as well as it's imperative core. It certainly has map, filter, reduce and it's extendable into composability (Search "Swift Point Free" if interested.).  In fact, I came to Haskell by following a thread from Swift to PointFree to Haskell). But yes - Haskell is purely functional so a different approach is certainly needed.

Answer (score 3):

Let

```
xs = [["","34","56","78"],["12","=","56","78"],["12","34","=","78"],["12","34","56",""]]
```

in

```
filter (not . any null) xs
```

will give

```
[["12","=","56","78"],["12","34","=","78"]]
```

If you want list comprehension then do

```
[x | x <- xs, and [not $ null y | y <- x]]
```

Comment: filter (not . any null) is more elegant - thanks.  but still has the issue that it creates 4 lists and then throws 2 away which I'd rather avoid.

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd probably do it this way. First, a preliminary that I've written so many times it's practically burned into my fingers by now:

```
zippers :: [a] -> [([a], a, [a])]
zippers = go [] where
    go _ [] = []
    go b (h:e) = (b,h,e):go (h:b) e
```

Probably running it once or twice in ghci will be a more clear explanation of what this does than any English writing I could do:

```
> zippers "abcd"
[("",'a',"bcd"),("a",'b',"cd"),("ba",'c',"d"),("cba",'d',"")]
```

In other words, it gives a way of selecting each element of a list in turn, giving the "leftovers" of what was before and after the selection point. Given that tool, here's our plan: we'll nondeterministically choose a `String` to serve as our equals sign, double-check that we've got an equals sign in the first place, and then clear out the equals from the others. So:

```
fixEquals ss = do
    (prefix, s, suffix) <- zippers ss
    guard ('=' `elem` s)
    return (reverse (deleteEquals prefix) ++ ["="] ++ deleteEquals suffix)

deleteEquals = map (filter ('='/=))
```

Let's try it:

```
> fixEquals ["12", "34=", "56=", "78"]
[["12","=","56","78"],["12","34","=","78"]]
```

Perfect! But this is just a stepping-stone to actually generating the equations, right? It turns out to be not that hard to go all the way in one step, skipping this intermediate. Let's do that:

```
equations ss = do
    (prefixes, s, suffixes) <- zippers ss
    guard ('=' `elem` s)
    prefix <- mapM (filter ('='/=)) (reverse prefixes)
    suffix <- mapM (filter ('='/=)) suffixes
    return (prefix ++ "=" ++ suffix)
```

And we can try it in ghci:

```
> equations ["12", "34=", "56=", "78"]
["1=57","1=58","1=67","1=68","2=57","2=58","2=67","2=68","13=7","13=8","14=7","14=8","23=7","23=8","24=7","24=8"]
```

Comment: This is very nice - thankyou - and you've gone further too which is useful.  I'm getting an issue - my compiler doesn't like the guard: I get: error: Variable not in scope: guard :: Bool -> [a0] and it underlines the word guard?

Comment: @Adahus `guard` is available from the `Control.Monad` module.

Comment: That sorts it - now works a treat.  Great stuff.  I stumbled across mapM before so good to see it in action. Thanks

Comment: @Adahus: If you run into `traverse`/`traverse_` (or their flipped cousins `for`/`for_`), they’re equivalent to the older `mapM`/`mapM_` and `forM`/`forM_`, but slightly more general in that they work on `Applicative` instead of `Monad`, just like `return` vs. `pure`. (As a matter of style I prefer to just always use the `Applicative` versions for consistency.)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest waty to achieve what you want is to create all the combinations and to filter the ones that have a meaning:

```
Prelude> test = ["12", "34=", "56=", "78"]
Prelude> sequence test
["1357","1358","1367","1368","13=7","13=8","1457","1458","1467","1468","14=7","14=8","1=57","1=58","1=67","1=68","1==7","1==8","2357","2358","2367","2368","23=7","23=8","2457","2458","2467","2468","24=7","24=8"
Prelude> filter ((1==).length.filter('='==)) $ sequence test
["13=7","13=8","14=7","14=8","1=57","1=58","1=67","1=68","23=7","23=8","24=7","24=8","2=57","2=58","2=67","2=68"]
```

You pointed the drawback: imagine we have the followig list of strings: `["=", "=", "0123456789", "0123456789"]`. We will generate 100 combinations and drop them all.

You can look at the combinations as a tree. For the `["12", "34"]`, you have:

```
  /  \
 1    2
/ \  / \
3 4  3 4
```

You can prune the tree: just ignore the subtrees when you have two `=` on the path.
Let's try to do it. First, a simple `combinations` function:

```
Prelude> :set +m
Prelude> let combinations :: [String] -> [String]
Prelude|     combinations [] = [""]
Prelude|     combinations (cs:ts) = [c:t | c<-cs, t<-combinations ts]
Prelude|
Prelude> combinations test
["1357","1358","1367","1368","13=7","13=8","1457","1458","1467","1468","14=7","14=8","1=57","1=58","1=67","1=68","1==7","1==8","2357","2358","2367","2368","23=7","23=8","2457","2458","2467","2468","24=7","24=8", ...]
```

Second, we need a variable to store the current number of `=` signs met:

- if we find a second `=` sign, just drop the subtree
- if we reach the end of a combination with no `=`, drop the combination

That is:

```
Prelude> let combinations' :: [String] -> Int -> [String]
Prelude|     combinations' [] n= if n==1 then [""] else []
Prelude|     combinations' (cs:ts) n = [c:t | c<-cs, let p = n+(fromEnum $ c=='='), p <= 1, t<-combinations' ts p]
Prelude|
Prelude> combinations' test 0
["13=7","13=8","14=7","14=8","1=57","1=58","1=67","1=68","23=7","23=8","24=7","24=8","2=57","2=58","2=67","2=68"]
```

- We use `p` as the new number of `=` sign on the path: if `p>1`, drop the subtree.
- If `n` is zero, we don't have any `=` sign in the path, drop the combination.

You may use the variable `n` to store more information, eg type of the last char (to avoid `+*` sequences).